# Java Play 2 - Updating manually

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, playframework-2.0, updates

Twitter just released bootstrap 2.1 and I want to update the helpers of play2.

the current rules are
https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/twitterBootstrap/twitterBootstrapFieldConstructor.scala.html

I went to `C:\play\framework\src\play\src\main\scala\views\helper\twitterBootstrap`

and changed it to:
(rules can be found here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms )

```
@(elements: views.html.helper.FieldElements)

@import play.api.i18n._
@import views.html.helper._

@**************************************************
* Generate input according twitter bootsrap rules *
**************************************************@

<div class="control-group error">
 <label class="control-label" for="@elements.id">@elements.label(elements.lang)</label>
 <div class="controls">
        @elements.input
        <span class="help-inline">@elements.errors(elements.lang).mkString(", ")</span>
        <span class="help-block">@elements.infos(elements.lang).mkString(", ")</span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

But i don't know how to update my project.

I did

```
play
clean
run
```

But it still uses the old rules, any ideas?

edit:

How do I use the twitter helper from the views?

```
@(signupForm: Form[User])

@import helper._


@title = {
    Sign Up
}

@main(title, nav = "signup") {

    @helper.form(action = routes.SignUp.submit) {

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account informations</legend>

            @inputText(
                signupForm("username"), 
                '_label -> "Username", 
                '_help -> "Please choose a valid username.",
                '_error -> signupForm.globalError
            )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently ran into similar Problems and ended up with creating my own Helper for this purpose.

Content of `app/views/Helpers/bootstrapInput.scala.html`:

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

@*****************************************************
* Generate input according to twitter bootsrap rules *
******************************************************@
<div class="control-group @if(elements.hasErrors) {error}">
  <label class="control-label" for="@elements.id">@elements.label</label>
  <div class="controls">
    @elements.input
    <span class="help-inline">@elements.errors(elements.lang).mkString(", ")</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And to use it put this in your view (on top, directly after declaring the parameters):

```
@implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(views.html.Helpers.bootstrapInput.f) }
```

Answer (score 2):

You updated the Play! source code, but you did not compile and package it.

The best way to change the helpers is to use them in your own project:

1. Put the new helpers in the `app/view` directory
2. Use them directly in your views without adding any import

Comment: Okay thanks, but how do I use them? (I updated my post.) I just want to render the errors, if the user made a mistake. So I need to tell play " hey use the error helper from the views!"

Comment: Please show where you put your new templates ? If it is in the `app/views` folder, you do not need the `@import helper._` statement in your view.

Comment: we should create a plugin for bootstrap2 with play

Answer (score 0):

There was also [pull request](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/217) on Github for fixing this in Play framework. Someone maybe can use [this commit](https://github.com/tschundeee/Play20/commit/8f40a211413baf0ddf3262709621c9b5bcdfab77) handy.